# warning Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, eslint

When i use this line:

```
this.state.selectedJobType.length > 0 ? 
    '' 
    : 
    this.setState({ jobTypeErrMsg: 'Please select at least one job type'});
```

It throws error:

> warning  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because ternary operator return the values on the basic of condition, and you are using ternary operator to update state, that's why.

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2;
```

Ternary operator execute the expressions [*expect the expressions that should result to some value, that can be a function call or directly any value*] and return the result of that expressions.

Use if condition instead of ternary operator, like this:

```
if(this.state.selectedJobType.length)
   this.setState({ jobTypeErrMsg: 'Please select at least one job type'})
```

Ternary operator works to assign the value on the basis of condition, like this:

```
let a = 0==0 ? 1 : 0;
```

Or you can use that inside JSX for `conditional rendering`, like this:

```
<div>{ 0==0 ? 'true' : 'false' }</div>
```

Or to call other function on the basis of condition:

```
1==1 ? a() : b();
```

[DOCs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

> Returns one of two expressions depending on a condition. If condition
>   is true, the operator returns the value of expr1; otherwise, it
>   returns the value of expr2.